# Color change dependent of an action (Button click)

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, android-resources

How can I create a Switch button in Android Studio (Java) that changes its track color  when its state is on ON (ex. black in ON state, red in OFF state).

I already tried to access to the colors in the `tack.xml` or `color.xml` but it don't know how to change them every time I turn the button ON/OFF especially the Background color of the Switch track (I was already able to change the Background of the whole Btn). Do you know how I could change the Background color of the Switch track?

Here is important part of my code (MainActivity):

```
private TextView switchState;
private Switch mySwitch;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    switchState = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.switchState);
    mySwitch = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);
    track = (trackColor)findViewById(R.id.trackColor);   //**!!

    // set the Switch to off
    mySwitch.setChecked(false);
    //now you need a listener to check changes in state
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                switchState.setText("Switch is ON!");

                mySwitch.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                trackColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); //**!!


            }else{
                switchState.setText("Switch is OFF!"); 



            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

(**!!) it cannot resolve the symbol `track` and `trackColor` and I can't explain why.**

**track.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="40dp"  />
    <gradient
        android:id="@+id/trackColor"/>
    <gradient
        android:height="40dp"
        android:startColor="#2979FF"
        android:endColor="#FFFF00"/>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in java code :

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
```

Then you can use the method setOnClicklistener to detect the click, and the method setBackGroundColor to change the color of the button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked. But after I tried to change the color of the Switch Btn track it failed and I couldn't figure out why. I edited my question so that you can see my code.

Comment: I don't understand where or how it failed ...Can explain what is the problem ? And we can't see enough code, do you have an "else" statement ?

Comment: I edited my question. Now you can see the "else" statement as well (but there is not the problem, the problem is that it cannot resolve the symbol `track` and `trackColor`.

Comment: You should declare at the begin the variable :
`private int track;`and then 
`track = (Integer) findViewById(R.id.trackcolor);`

Comment: Thanks. But how am I able to access to the `android:startColor="#2979FF"` and `android:endColor="#FFFF00"`. And how can I change them (because they already have a fixed color)? @PaLaSeul

Comment: I don't know how the Switch object works, and i can't help you anymore. But the title of your question is resolved so you should maybe marked it as resolved and ask a new question with your new question, a better way to reach people that can help you... @jessica3047